# How to get the calender from 10.04 or a similar alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, 10.04, calendar

I'm still running Ubuntu 10.04 on my older computer, since I always get one problem or another when I upgrade. I've managed to solve most of them on my newer computer, but I can't figure out how to get the old calendar back. Does anyone know?

#### Alternatively, is there another calendar that has these features?

- Lets you add different locations.
- Shows the weather in different locations.
- Shows the number of the week.

This is the calendar I'm talking about:
[image: 10.04 calender screen-shot]

Comment: Support for 10.04 Desktop ended in 2013, when Lucid Desktop went End of Life.

Comment: @ThomasW. yes, but the question is not about 10.04 --- it's about a recent version. Read the second phrase of the question. The OP is victim of the user interface simplification trend...

Comment: @Rmano if you read his question, the OP states they are still using 10.04.  They **actually say that** in the first line.  That alone is EOL.

Comment: @ThomasW I understand that he wants a calendar in his **newer** computer (second period) that is similar to the old one running 10.04. Berrjod, would you chime in? Which version is running in your newer computer?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there are no modern calender apps for Ubuntu that do this, but he can get the two features separately.

Comment: AFAIK, the only missing feature to the 14.04 calendar is the line where the sun shines: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KzY0n.png

Comment: That was gnome-panel clock applet. You can not use it with Unity. You have to use it with gnome-flashback session. Install it using `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-flashback`. then log out & choose flashback(compiz) from session at login screen

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Can you expand on how to get this set up in the applet? I've used gnome-flashback several times but never seen an applet like this by default.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running on your newer computer?

Comment: @Seth First you have to remove Ubuntu's indicator applet(which is indicator-applet-all) from panel(press win+alt+right-click & select remove). Then add following applets (from left to right): `indicator-session`, `clock` & finally `indicator-applet`. See the image: http://i.imgur.com/kDFuO1r.png

Answer (score 2):

The calendar in Ubuntu (current versions) can show the day of the week as well as different locations. If you have trouble enabling these from the standard system settings, then install `unity-tweak-tool` to enable those features.

However, as for showing the weather in the calendar, this is no longer possible. You'd need to install a weather indicator, such as My-Weather-Indicator.

Instructions to install it are below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/my-weather-indicator-version-066.html

*I will update this answer later with screenshots and further instructions.*

Answer (score 1):

That was old gnome-panel's clock applet. You can not use it with Unity. You have to use it with gnome-flashback session.

- First install it using

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-flashback indicator-session indicator-applet
  ```
- Then logout & from login-screen choose `Flashback(compiz)` session & log in.
  By default it will give you the old desktop like in 10.04. But it is still using indicator-datetime. So you need to remove it.
- Move mouse over the applet, press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>, **right click** & select remove. This should remove all the indicator-applets from panel area.
- Now add following applets (**starting from LEFT-to-RIGHT**) to the panel:

  - `indicator-session`
  - `clock`
  - `indicator-applet`

Now your desktop will look like this:

[image]

DONE!